# custom scrollbar with a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

im new to javascript programming and i want to add a custom scrollbar to my bootstrap page. i have found jQuery.NiceScroll.
i have made a javascript file with the code below:

```
 $(document).ready(
function() {  
  $("html").niceScroll();
});
```

and added before closing body

```
<link href="newjavascript.js" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

what im doing wrong ?

Comment: Is your javascript file the one you're trying to include as a stylesheet ?

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong, try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/n57gV/, and the order is important.